# Replace dictionary key with reference to another dictionary which acts as glossary for the key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a python dictionary which is some kind of a glossary.

```
glossary_dict = {'AA': 'AA_meaning',
                 'BB': 'BB_meaning',
                 'CC': 'CC_meaning',
                 }
```

Here is the original dictionary.

```
original = [{'AA': '299021.000000'},
            {'BB': '299021.000000'},
            {'CC': '131993.000000'},
            ]
```

I want to replace the keys of `original` dictionary with the corresponding value of `glossary_dict`.
The final result will look like this;

```
explained = {'AA_meaning': '299021.000000',
             'BB_meaning': '299021.000000',
             'CC_meaning': '131993.000000',
            }
```

I am using python 3.7

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: You can not "replace" a key in a dict - you could add the replacement keys and delete the original ones or you can create a new dict thats fixed to your liking. Simplest way would be a loop, bit more tough is a dict comp. Try both ways and post where you got hang up if research does not help you fix it yourself.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I think I have worked out the answer. HOld on.

Comment: Then just delete the question

Comment: @jonrsharpe No. I will put the answer here for future references. Who knows? Might be useful to others. That's the purpose of stack overflow.

Comment: I really don't think something that's both so trivial to reimplement and so specific to your context will be findable and useful to anyone else.

Comment: It wasn't trivial to me. YOu cannot assume others are as smart as you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or if we want even more unreadable:

```py
{glossary_dict.get(*o.keys()): o.get(*o.keys()) for o in original}
```

Good stuff too cause it uses `*` unpacking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer for my own question.

```
new_dict = {}
for index in range(len(original)):
    for key in original[index]:
        new_dict[glossary_dict[key]] = original[index][key]

print(new_dict)
```

Another more elegant method is using dictionary comprehension. Answer is provided by Rakesh[https://stackoverflow.com/a/61906060/3848207]. I'll put it here for easier reference.

```
explained = {glossary_dict[key]: value for i in original for key, value in i.items()}
print(explained)
```

Comment: This depends on dictionary order (and therefore potentially give the wrong results), why don't you iterate over the *list*? It could be a one-line list comprehension that way.

Comment: List comprehension is easy to read, difficult to write, at least to me.

Comment: You don't *have* to use a list comprehension, I suppose, but either way iterating over `original` rather than `glossary_dict` would be much simpler and less prone to errors. Also incrementing an index is rarely the idiomatic way to loop.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I totally changed the answer. Thanks for pointing out that the previous answer depends on dictionary order. New answer should work better.

Comment: Did you test it out? It won't.

Comment: There's only one dictionary in the list, that's not the output your question required...

Comment: @jonrsharpe, thanks again for pointing out the mistake of only one dictionary in the list which was not what the original question wanted. I was so dumb that I could not even recognise the mistake. I have edited the original question because it is simpler to have a single dictionary output than a list of multiple dictionaries. I have also edited the answer. It should be correct this time.