# What's wrong with this dictionary comprehension code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have a python dictionary which is some kind of a glossary.

```
glossary_dict = {'AA': 'AA_meaning',
                 'BB': 'BB_meaning',
                 'CC': 'CC_meaning',
                 }
```

Here is the original dictionary.

```
original = [{'AA': '299021.000000'},
            {'BB': '299021.000000'},
            {'CC': '131993.000000'},
            ]
```

I want to replace the keys of `original` dictionary with the corresponding value of `glossary_dict`.
The final result will look like this;

```
explained = {'AA_meaning': '299021.000000',
             'BB_meaning': '299021.000000',
             'CC_meaning': '131993.000000',
            }
```

I want to solve this problem using dictionary comprehension approach. This is what I did;

```
explained = {glossary_dict[key]: value for (key, value) in original[0].items()}
```

The result is `{'AA_meaning': '299021.000000'}`. It is close but still not the correct answer. What did I miss out?

I am using python 3.7

Comment: Your second dictionary is a list of dictionaries. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Nikolas Stevenson-Molnar, yes

Comment: In that case, I expect Rakesh's answer will do what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a list of `dict`s, Iterate the list and then access the key

**Ex:**

```
explained = {glossary_dict[key]: value for i in original for key, value in i.items()}
print(explained)
```

**Output:**

```
{'AA_meaning': '299021.000000',
 'BB_meaning': '299021.000000',
 'CC_meaning': '131993.000000'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct your `explained` dictionary first. Then, use,

`original = [{'AA': '299021.000000'},
            {'BB': '299021.000000'},
            {'CC': '131993.000000'},
            ]`

to

`original = {'AA': '299021.000000',
            'BB': '299021.000000',
            'CC': '131993.000000'}`

Then,

`explained = {glossary_dict[key]: value for (key, value) in original.items()}`